# Android - Send and receive byte

Tags: java, android

I've a tcp connection and i try to send and receive messages in byte, but I don't know how it work.

Here is my code to send:

```
public void write(String message) {
    try {
        byte[] b = message.getBytes("UTF-8");
        writer.write(b.toString());
        writer.newLine();
        writer.flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(MainActivity.TAG, "exception", e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(MainActivity.TAG, "exception", e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and this for receive

```
String message = client.reader.readLine();
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(message);
```

---

I try again :)

How I can convert the received byte array to string with full unicode for the mysql database? I use charset Utf8m4 for my database.

This is my code

```
byte[] message = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(client.reader.ReadLine()); // client.reader.ReadLine() is already a byte[]

string encoded = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message);
JToken token = JObject.Parse(encoded);
```

My code isn't work. I get:

```
{"Id":"Test","Content":"hey???"}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: How i can send and receive the messages in byte array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    byte[] b = message.getBytes("UTF-8");
    writer.write(b.toString());
```

If this is the code you're asking abut, it is senseless. It should of course be

```
writer.write(message);
```

At present you're sending something of the form `[B@NNNNNNNNNNN`, which is the hashcode of a byte array.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution, thank's to @EJP.

In java (client side)

```
writer.write(B64.encode(message)); // message is a string
```

In C# (server side)

```
string encoded = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message);
JToken token = JObject.Parse(encoded);
```

To save the bytes in database i use blob as type.

```
Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(bluuub)
```

To get the bytes from database

```
byte[] b = (byte[])reader.GetValue(0);
string bluuub = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(b);
```